# add values to data frame for only some specific elements - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With these two data frames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','b','c','d'],'c2':[10,20,10,22]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c3':['e','f','a','g','b','c','r','j','d'],'c4':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
```

I'm trying to add the values of `c4` to `df1` for only the elements in `c3` that are also present in `c1`:

```
>>> df1
  c1  c2  c4
  a   10  3  
  b   20  5
  c   10  6
  d   22  9
```

Is there a simple way of doing this in pandas?

UPDATE:

If

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c3':['e','f','a','g','b','c','r','j','d'],'c4':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]},'c5':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90])
```

how can I achieve this result?

```
>>> df1
  c1  c2  c4  c5
  a   10  3   30  
  b   20  5   50
  c   10  6   60
  d   22  9   90
```

Doing:

```
>>> df1['c1'].map(df2.set_index('c3')['c4','c5'])
```

gives me a `KeyError`

Comment: You should not modify your question and change your requirements, if you have a new question then post a new question, anyway `df1.merge(df2, left_on='c1', right_on='c3').drop('c3', axis=1)` is what you want

Comment: @EdChum: Ok, I'll do it next time. Many thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `map` on `df2['c4']` after setting the index on `df2['c3']`, this will perform a lookup:

```
In [239]:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','b','c','d'],'c2':[10,20,10,22]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c3':['e','f','a','g','b','c','r','j','d'],'c4':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
df1['c4'] = df1['c1'].map(df2.set_index('c3')['c4'])
df1

Out[239]:
  c1  c2  c4
0  a  10   3
1  b  20   5
2  c  10   6
3  d  22   9
```

Comment: Is it actually possible to call "map" on more than one column? I have updated my example.

Comment: To answer your question, no it won't work that way, for your updated example use merge